# The reason for the inequality $|z^n|>(|a_1|+\ldots+|a_n|)|z^{n-1}|>|a_1z^{n-1}|+\ldots+|a_n|$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, complex-numbers

For a complex polynomial $p(z)=z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n$ and for a real number $r\geq0$. For a large value of $r$, bigger than $|a_1|+\ldots+|a_n|$ and bigger than 1. Then for $|z|=r$,

how can we have

$|z^n|>(|a_1|+\ldots+|a_n|)|z^{n-1}|>|a_1z^{n-1}|+\ldots+|a_n|$ ?

I sort of get the second inequality, is it true if I say for a large $|z|=r$, $|z^{n-1}|>|z^{n-2}|$, and hence the second inequality follows?

I am not sure about the first inequality? Could anybody please give some help? Thanks.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi Did you mean $|z^n|=|z||z|\ldots|z|$ $n$ times, but the right hand side contains no $|z^n|$? I don't quite understand how the factoring out creates the inequality?

Comment: oops sorry - ignore that last comment.

Comment: $|z^n| = |z|^n$ so you know the values of $|z^n|$ if you assume $|z| = r$..... ie
$$|z^n| = |z|^n= r^n = r \cdot r^{n-1} > (|a_1|+...+|a_n|)r^{n-1},$$
since $r > (|a_1|+...+|a_n|).$

Comment: @Zestylemonzi thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|z^n|>(|a_1|+\ldots+|a_n|)|z^{n-1}|$ equivalent $r^n>(|a_1|+\ldots+|a_n|)r^{n-1}$ which is true because $r \gt |a_1|+\ldots+|a_n|$

$(|a_1|+\ldots+|a_n|)|z^{n-1}|>|a_1z^{n-1}|+\ldots+|a_n|$ equivalent $(|a_1|+\ldots+|a_n|)>|a_1|+ |a_2| \frac 1 {|z|} \ldots+|a_n|\frac 1 {|z|^{n-1}}$ which is true because $\frac 1 {|z|^{k}} \lt 1$